# Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.+

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic4

I'm working on Ionic Project , when trying building an APK using Cordova 
(ionic cordova build android) i face this error despite that few days ago it used to work perfectly . i tried all the proposed solutions around the web . 
Any help will be good

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 11.0.4
       - 11.0.2
       - 11.0.1
       - 11.0.0
       - 10.2.6
       - + 35 more
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. I normally see people having issues with it with Google Services though.

I don't know the exact correct terminology, but different packages depend on different versions and they aren't compatible.

There are plugins that automatically fix this for when it happens with Google Services but I'm not sure about this one.

You can override this manually though by tweaking the Gradle file.

You might be able to solve this a better way though by ensuring all of your firebase related packages are updated to their latest versions in `package.json`.

If that doesn't work it's going to be a more complicated process of finding all the incorrect references in the gradle files and updating them to target a single common version.

## update

I just noticed you said this:

> i face this error despite that few days ago it used to work perfectly

If that's the case then which plugin did you add to your project in the last few days. It's probably out of date and the cause of your issues.

Comment: Thanks for answering and for your time , can you explain how i can override this manually by tweaking the Gradle file . at least this may be  temporary until i figure out the plugin is the issue .

Comment: I dont know exactly, but you should look for `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` in your gradle files